# Does the C++ Standard allow the addition of two integers (fundamental type int) to throw a C++ exception?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Does the Standard allow this?

I don't think it does. Someone does. I need intelligent people to prove him wrong.

Comment: @iammilind: random person on the interwebz.

Comment: obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/386/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it does. The overflow of signed integers is undefined behavior, so anything could happen (including an exception being thrown).

As a side note, I must say this is unlikely to happen (yet definitely *possible*) for most implementations; as the C++11 Standard mentions in a note to paragraph 5/4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
>   representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [ **Note: most existing implementations of C++
>   ignore integer overflows**. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all
>   floating point exceptions vary among machines, and is usually adjustable by a library function. —end note ]

[As hvd mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636073/does-the-c-standard-allow-the-addition-of-two-integers-fundamental-type-int/16636091?noredirect=1#comment23924141_16636091), however, some implementations allow to provide custom handlers for integer overflow, and those handlers may throw.

Comment: Subtle, but definitely possible!

Comment: Since integer addition is basically C, not C++, I don't believe *any* compiler would ever throw an exception for it.

Comment: (though I don't disagree that the standard technically allows it)

Comment: @Dave: Very unlikely, indeed, but formally possible ;)

Comment: It's not extremely unlikely. clang allows a custom handler to be set for integer overflow (compile with `-ftrapv` and `-ftrapv-handler ...`), and why wouldn't that custom handler throw an exception if the code is part of a C++ project?

Comment: @hvd: I didn't know that, will have to edit. Thank you for mentioning!

Comment: @Dave Exceptions can happen in C; For example GNU/Linux implements POSIX cancelation points using exceptions. E.g. `fopen` can throw an exception when the thread is canceled.

Comment: @AndyProwl: How about this question _"Does the **C++ Standard** allow the addition of two integers to throw a C++ exception **deliberately** (not based on random chance due to UB)?"_

Comment: @MM.: Sounds like another question :)

Comment: @AndyProwl: and I think you have an answer for that, isn't it?

Comment: @MM.: I think I do, but others may have a better one

Answer (score 4):

The rule of thumb is anything that is can be written in C cannot and should not throw an exception...

Therefore, it wouldn't.

As Andy says, this behavior is undefined so anything can happen. In theory the computer could also go make you a cup of coffee and take your dog for a walk. However if you were in a job interview, I would suggest you tell them no :)

Comment: Ill-conceived rules are known to hurt thumbs. You cannot write "it" in C because signed overflow in C is not allowed, just like in C++.

Comment: `sizeof('a')` can be written in C but it results in different vaulue (and do on most platforms). Besides - undefined behaviour on C might result in exception - try integer division by zero which results in hardware exception on many platforms (given it is not a C++ exception...).